# SOAP HTTPS Services consume in c#

Tags: c#, soap, basichttpbinding

I am trying to consume HTTPS SOAP Service which has credentials to authorise it and get the below error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '

Bindings are below. Am I missing anything?

```
<endpoint address="https://...."
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IInboundService1"
          contract="RQSInboundExternal.IInboundService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IInboundServiceQSPort">

<basicHttpBinding>              
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IInboundService1" >                  
              <security mode="Transport" >
               <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>                   
              </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: It sounds like you tried to consume XML from the resource and it returned an HTML page to you instead.

Comment: yes. I will have to send the credentials via headers. How do i need to send that?  I am getting a logout page back. This happens when there is  credentials mismatch. But the same credentails work with soupui and browser.

Answer (score 0):

set username and password here. This is also required to be sent. If we only send in the header it is not working.

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "";

var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
httpRequestProperty.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
            client.Open();
            var context = new OperationContext(client.InnerChannel);
            using (new OperationContextScope(context))
            {
                context.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;

                client.SampleMethodCall();
            }
```